How can we retrieve the last streamed value from a publisher inside the sink closure of another publisher?
In Swift Combine, suppose we have two publishers:
let publisher1 = AnyPublisher<String, Never>()
let publisher2 = AnyPublisher<Int, Never>()

Note: The type of the publisher are not relevant.
How can we retrieve the last streamed value from publisher2 inside the sink closure of publisher1?
One solution could be use combineLatest modifier
let combinedPublisher = Publishers.CombineLatest(publisher1, publisher2)

but it would means we get notified when publisher2 or publisher1 gets a new value. I would like to only subscribe to changes on publisher1.
To clarify the issue I need to address:
Within my ViewModel, I utilize an AnyPublisher that signals when a screen refresh is required. Within this process, I use the map operator to generate a new publisher. The function responsible for generating this new publisher requires the most recent state of the ViewModel to prepend to the generated publisher. However, to prevent concurrency issues, I aim to exclude accessing the "oldState" within the map. Please see the code snippet below for context.
@Published private(set) var myState: State = .initial

func bindMyData() {
    myRefreshUseCase.publisher
      .receive(on: DispatchQueue.ui)
      .combineLatest($myState) // I want to alway get the latest value of state, but don't want to trigger the stream pipeline if State is updated
      .map { _, oldState in fetchNewDataPublisher(preapend: oldState) }
      .switchToLatest()
      .assign(to: \.loadingState, onWeak: self)
      .store(in: &disposables)
  }


Please provide a real use case, since with the current overly simplified example, this seems like an XY problem.

@DávidPásztor check if the question got any better

A PassthroughSubject does not maintain its latest value (hence the word passthrough).  After its value is published there is no way to retrieve the last value.  A CurrentValueSubject does maintain the last value it published.
import UIKit
import Combine

let publisher1 = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
let publisher2 = CurrentValueSubject<Int, Never>(0)

let subscription = publisher1
  .print()
  .sink { stringValue in
    print ("The value of Publisher1 is \(stringValue) and publisher 2 is \(publisher2.value)")
}


publisher1.send("Hello")
publisher2.send(5)
publisher1.send("World")

